# C# windows 8 app scrollview

Tags: c#, windows, scrollview, visual-studio-2013

I can't seem to set up the scrollview right. I can use scrollbar scrollview or whatever, I just want the scroll function.

Code:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="65" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="65" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="65" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="65" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="65" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="65" />
        <RowDefinition Height="65" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried setting `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` on the Grid?

Comment: Yes I have...................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use [`Grid.RowDefinitions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.rowdefinitions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) under a grid:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="65" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="65" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="65" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="65" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="65" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="65" />
            <RowDefinition Height="65" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I suspect that was your problem.

**Simplified example:**
You can use just one scroll viewer for the entire page. This scroll viewer can have a grid with several rows (or columns). Then you can add any control and assign them to a row:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="400"/>
        <TextBlock Text="2" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="400"/>
        <TextBlock Text="3" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="400"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[image]

**To Not Shift the Whole Page**
You can create a grid outside the scroll viewer like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="400"/>
            <TextBlock Text="2" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="400"/>
            <TextBlock Text="3" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="400"/>
       </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock 
            Text="outside of ScrollView control"
            Foreground="Red" FontSize="50"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: That is correct. You will probably also want to disable scrollviewer zooming, which is for some unknown reason enabled by default.

Comment: But the entire segment is in a grid already. The big grid for the page. If I put another grid in, the template gets messed up.

Comment: I'm not too sure if you can specify rows within a control in a grid.

Comment: What should I do then to have a scroll function. If I have a lot of buttons, should I just put them in one row?

Comment: @user3155730, you can place the controls inside the ScrollView and assign them each a row.

Comment: so scrollview for each single row?

Comment: @user3155730, one scrollview that has a grid with child controls.

Comment: <scrollview><grid.childrenrowdefinitions>?

Comment: @user3155730, hold on a sec. I'll add an example in my post.

Comment: nevermind. how can I only get the content to shift not the entire app page tho.